# how can I read through such a corpus?

Tags: python-3.x, nltk

Actually I'm going to make an HMM POS tagger for persian. I'm working on a corpus like the following. The first column on the left consists of Persian words and the second column on the right, the POS tags. 
My question is that how I can read through it, tokenize it based on sentences, then save the tags and words in a list as the codes below do ?

```
words = [nltk.word_tokenize(s) for s in sentences]
tagged = [nltk.pos_tag(w) for w in words]
```

Any suggestions or codes which can help me?

```
    #                                             DELM
اولين                                             ADJ_SUP
سياره                                             N_SING
خارج                                              ADJ_SIM
از                                                P
منظومه                                            N_SING
شمسي                                              ADJ_SIM
ديده                                              ADJ_INO
شد                                                V_PA
.                                                 DELM
#                                                 DELM
#                                                 DELM
واشنگتن                                           N_SING
ـ                                                 DELM
خبرگزاري                                          N_SING
جمهوري                                            N_SING
اسلامي                                            ADJ_SIM
#                                                 DELM
ستاره شناسان                                      N_PL
مي گويند                                          V_PRS
كه                                                CON
ممكن                                              ADJ_SIM
است                                               V_PRE
اولين                                             ADJ_SUP
سياره                                             N_SING
خارج                                              ADJ_SIM
از                                                P
منظومه                                            N_SING
شمسي                                              ADJ_SIM
را                                                P
ديده                                              ADJ_INO
باشند                                             V_SUB
.                                                 DELM
```

Comment: What's your file format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a dictionary of your words with splitting the lines with space,but note that since you have space between your words you can use `re` module to split based on 3 space or more  :

```
import re
with open('out.txt') as f:
    tags=dict(map(lambda x:re.split(r' {3,}',x.strip()),f))
```

Then you can get the proper tag with indexing :

```
print (tags['منظومه'])
'N_SING'
```

Then in your main text when you want tag your words you can split your text which based on your need you can use simple string `split` method or regex, then replace the word with its corresponding items in your `tags` dictionary.

Example :

```
s='اولين سياره خارج از منظومه شمسي ديده شد.'

tagged_sentence=[(i,tags[i]) for i in re.findall(r'\w+|\S+',s) if i]

print (tagged_sentence)
[('اولين', 'ADJ_SUP'), ('سياره', 'N_SING'), ('خارج', 'ADJ_SIM'), ('از', 'P'), ('منظومه', 'N_SING'), ('شمسي', 'ADJ_SIM'), ('ديده', 'ADJ_INO'), ('شد', 'V_PA'), ('.', 'DELM')]
```

Note that here you can not use `str.split()` method because you have a dot at the end of your sentence and there is no space between your last word and the dot.So I used `re.findall` to find all the words (combinations with length 1 or more of word characters (`\w+`) ) and none white space characters (`\S+`).

If you want to extract your sentence you need to split your corpus based on dot or precisely using following regex then use `map` and `zip` :

```
import re
with open('out.txt') as f:
    all_sentences=re.findall(r'([^.]*\.[^\n]*)',f.read())

persian_sent=[zip(*map(lambda x:re.split(r' {3,}',x.strip()),i.split('\n'))) for i in all_sentences if i]
```

So after that yo'll have your Persian sentences within a first indices of nested list within `persian_sent`,and tags in second index.

You can get your sentences by doing :

```
for i in persian_sent:
    print ''.join(list(i)[0])
```

Also note that since `zip` in python 3 returns a generator you need to convert it to list when you want to index it!

Comment: but first I need to detect the sentences and tokenize based on them, then have to add sentence beginning tokens such as ( "<s>", "<s>"). With a dictionary I don't think it's possible.

Comment: actually you defined the sentence yourself but how can I define it having a dictionary of words and tags. I applied whatever u did here but there was an error:  Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    tagged_sentence=[(i,tags[i]) for i in re.findall(r'\w+|\S+',s) if i]
NameError: name 's' is not defined

Comment: @marysd How you want to get your text for tagging? this error says that you have not defined the name `s` because that's my variable name ;). So did you putted your sentence in a variable or you want to read from a file or ...?

Comment: I want to read the sentences in the same way u read from the dictionary but you define the sentence as s yourself. I didn't put the sentences in a variable. The question is that How I can do when I only have a dictionary of tags and words? :-) By the way thanks for your reply. :-)

Comment: I can't enter the chatroom 'cause I only have 19 reputations.